Power automate import outlook email to excel
I am using Power automate I'm trying to import emails to excel. All new emails automatically added in my excel but I want to add old or existing email.Can you help me if there's a way to add old mails in my excel?
Thank you
Only new emails added in my excel I want to add specific email on it.
